# When should I use -sreg in WiX' HEAT.EXE?

Tags: deployment, wix

I'm using HEAT to autogenerate WiX fragments for a directory of files.

The project I'm deploying is an ASP.NET project. When I tried to harvest a directory, HEAT generates `RegistryValue` entries that writes InProcServer32 entries for .NET DLLs.

Using -sreg removes said entries.

Questions:

1. Should I even be using HEAT to
   autogenerate fragments? I've read
   everywhere that I should not be
   doing this. When should I use HEAT?
2. Should I always use -sreg? What if
   I'm deploying COM objects?
3. What is the downside of using -sreg
   when distributing .NET assemblies?

*Sorry, new to WiX and deployment as a whole. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. In my opinion heat should be used as a first pass to generate a fragment. Opinions vary on this and many people like to use it in a build process.
2. Only use -sreg if would don't want the registry values. If you have COM you would want them. This is where answer 1 comes in, I think you run heat then edit the output to suit what you want to do.
3. Depends, .NET itself doesn't need the registry values but if you use COM it will. What values do you get for non-com assemblies?

Comment: Neil, what do you mean by "values do you get for non-com assemblies"?

Comment: You wrote "HEAT generates RegistryValue entries" I just wonder whether any of these were not COM registry entries.